# tf metrics with tf.math.count_nonzero

Tags: tensorflow, metrics

playing with tensorflow I wrote a simple metrics function :

```
def custom__error(y_true, y_pred):
  ytrue = tf.round(y_true)
  ypred = tf.round(y_pred)
  z = tf.math.equal(ytrue, ypred)
  return tf.math.count_nonzero(z,axis=1)
```

As count_nonzero is only counting , I expected to recover integer values and not decimals : **custom__error: 0.3524** ...

```
1802/1802 [=...==] - 0s 192us/step - loss: 52.3571 - accuracy: 1.0000 - custom__error: 0.3524
```

What is done inside the metric callback to get decimal value ?

```
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy',custom__error])
```

Comment: I think those metrics are taken per example, and then Keras averages them for the whole batch.

Comment: Thanks , it seems like, but I didn't find anything about this

Comment: @Peter Sorry, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I gave a point to jdehese and thanked him.
What should I do to be correct?